# IE8 Rendering extra Padding or Margin

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, rendering, margin

I'm having with some margin or padding issues with IE8 that I'm hoping someone here will be able to help me out. Below is a screenshot of the site in IE7 with the correct spacing (it looks pretty much the same in FF and Chrome/Safari as well).

[alt text http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/9376/screenshot20100721at749.png](http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/9376/screenshot20100721at749.png)

Next is the same page in IE8 with a whole bunch of extra spacing between the created by line and description.

[alt text http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/9376/screenshot20100721at749.png](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/9376/screenshot20100721at749.png)

You can take a look at the live site [here](http://play.inspire2go.com/wanderlists/5-Most-Romantic-Restaurants-in-Ottawa). I've messed around with the padding and margins without any luck, I have no idea where the extra space is coming from. Inspecting the element using the IE developer tools shows an offset that doesn't add up to me, but I'm not sure why this would be happening.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `SPAN` at the end of `<span style="padding-left: 10px">1 Voter<span>`. It should be a closing tag. Change this code to:

```
<span style="padding-left: 10px">1 Voter</span>
```

This will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! been staring at this html for a couple days and just not seeing it.

Comment: No problem. It happens to us all. I like the site you're developing. Nice advertisement for our city (and other cities). :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from the `div` containing `The best places for sharing a meal with someone special.` and replace the div with a `p`. See what happens. Adjacent vertical margins should collapse properly.